# Keith Wood datepicker change function not working

Tags: jquery

Some simple pieces of code;

```
<form  action="#" method="post">       
    <div  id='datepicker'>
      <label for="start_date">Start of cover</label>
      <input readonly required="required" type='text'  name="start-date" id="start-date" value=""/>
    </div>
    <input  name="bind" id ="get-bind" type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
```

The `input`, `#start-date` has Keith Wood's datepick jQuery extension. Works fine.

But it doesn't trigger the change event so that the 2nd part of this code (both wrapped in `$(document).ready` doesn't work;

```
$('#get-bind').attr("disabled", true);

$('#start-date').change(function() {
     window.alert ("Changed!");
    $('#get-bind').attr("disabled", false);
});
```

I can see, in the debugger, that the change function is properly bound, it's just that the datepicker doesn't trigger it, even though the value is actually changing.

There's a small problem in that the datepicker seems to remove the required nature of the date field, even though the attribute is still there in the code like this;

```
<input readonly required name="start-date" id="start-date" value="" class="is-datepick" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer (which is the same as jQuery's Datepicker is that events to the target field are ignored so you have to use events within the datepicker itself.

```
$('#start-date').datepick({

    onClose: function() {
        $('#get-bind').attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

to be a bit more helpful, I needed to check whether a date had been chosen because onClose fires even if a date is not chosen, I did this;

```
 onClose: function() {
        if ($('#start-date').val()) {
            $('#get-bind').attr("disabled", false);
        }

    }
```

so that if a date has not been chosen the submit button remains disabled.